# Excel Chart to use same range when new rows are added

Tags: excel

I am trying to get my Graph/Chart to recognize the new row that is added by a macro. For example, the chart's range is cells B2:F22 which works fine. However, when I run my macro, the macro inserts a new row above B2 and populates it with data. The chart however, changes to B3:F23 rather than staying with B2:F22 no matter what rows comes in. Any ideas on how to force it to stay with B2:F22? I tried doing $B$2:$F$22 but that didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line of code at the end of your macro so its sets chart new range after adding the line.

```
    Charts(1).SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(1).Range("B2:F22")
```

Comment: If I have multiple charts, how do I know what chart to reference?

Comment: MSDN Uses that same code except it doesnt explain how you know whether the chart you are trying to refer to is Chart (1) or Chart (10)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that cell B1 is a header cell that doesn't move, use a calculated range for the series data. eg. Create a named range with the formula 
=OFFSET($B$1,1,0,21,1), and use that range name for the series data.

Comment: The chart isn't for just column B it needs from B1:F22 (Row one is the headers for each of the columns.) Additionally, would that just be something I would put in the Select data range?